# File over SFTP shows additonal chars at the beginning

Tags: php, symfony, csv, sftp, phpseclib

I've a function in symfony 3.4 which throws chars that do not exist in file:

```
use Exception;
use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper;

public static function getInfoFile(string $fileName, ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $host = $container->getParameter('host');
    $sftp = new SFTP($host);
    if (!$sftp->login($container->getParameter('user'), $container->getParameter('pass'))) {
        throw new Exception('Cannot connect to ' . $host);
    }
    $file = $sftp->get("/info/$fileName");

    vardumper::dump($file); // See Response below

    $file = preg_split('/\R/', $file);
    reset($file);

    // vardumper::dump($file); // This would now return each array element prepended with b"""

    return $file;
}
```

This returns:

> Service.php on line 30: b""" A;B;C;D;E;F\r\n 1;2;3;4;5;6\r\n

This b""" is nowhere in the file. I've tried to open with Notepad++ and Excel and this cannot be seen.

When I try to use substr with this, then b""" stays and real file is cut.

What am i doing wrong?
I would like to read the csv file for each line into an array without these cryptic b"""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution....

```
$file = $sftp->get("/info/$fileName");
$file = mb_convert_encoding($file, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-15" ); // Add this
```

The problem was the encoding.